# How "strong" is Pine Sol as a solvent?

Tags: solvents

How "strong" of a solvent is Pine Sol? Is it relatively benign like Isopropyl Alcohol, stronger like Acetone, or ridiculous like TCE?

Without a background in chemistry (mine is electrical engineering), I'm trying to get a "feel" for what materials I can use what solvents on.

For example, *"strong"* solvents shouldn't be used on wood, plastic, etc whereas *"moderate"* ones can't be used on thin/"weak" plastics but sturdier plastics are OK for short periods of time (i.e. I can use them for cleaning a plastic welding mask in the garage but shouldn't use them on the plastic LCD screen).

If I'm asking the wrong questions, please feel free to answer the question I should have been asking - but keep in mind I'm looking right now for the medium-fidelity answer, not the 100%-physically-correct-by-understanding-chemical-bonds answer.

Comment: According the Clorox Company: Water acts as a base. C10-12 alcohol ethoxylates and sodium C14-17 secondary alkyl sulfonate are grease-cutting surfactants, or cleaning agents, used in cleaning products such as laundry detergent. Glycolic acid is used to remove soap scum, discoloration and scale deposits in toilets and bathtubs. Dimethicone/silica/PEG distearates are used mainly as defoamers. Caramel is added to improve the product's appearance and to let the consumer know if the product is working when it is applied. Xanthan gum is used as a biodegradable thickener.

Comment: To be able to know how harmful a substance is, you would need to take a look at its ingredients.

Comment: Also, strong is a rather qualitative term. I assumed that you are interested in whether the substance is safe to handle. Maybe you meant something else?

Comment: Without a background in chemistry (but an electrical engineering background), I'm trying to get a "feel" for what materials I can use what solvents on - e.g. "strong" solvents shouldn't be used on wood, plastic, etc whereas "moderate" ones can't be used on thin/"weak" plastics but sturdier plastics are OK for short periods of time (i.e. I can use them for cleaning a plastic welding mask in the garage but shouldn't use them on the plastic LCD screen).

Comment: If I'm asking the wrong questions, please feel free to answer the question I should have been asking - but keep in mind I'm looking right now for the medium-fidelity answer, not the 100%-physically-correct-by-understanding-chemical-bonds answer.